# Face book and twitter integration to iphone app not working on device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter

I am very new to iOS development.I am making an application in which i required to integrate twitter and Facebook for wall posting.
I have done all the required coding for this and on simulator it is working fine but not on device.

one more question as the coding for Facebook integration i have copied it from other "demo" application.So what else we need to change in it to make it for my own application.Because when i see my update done by my app on Facebook wall, "demo" app name comes there with the post.

Please guide me !!Thanking you in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook**

It seems you have jumped to coding part before reading the documentation. Before integrating facebook sdk and writing your code, you need create a new app section in facebook developer console, get an Facebook app id. You need to use that app id in your project, not the app id shipped with facebook demo application.

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) explains the process fully, no need to rewrite it here. Make sure you read it to the end.

**Twitter**

I am not sure if you are having problem in twitter also (question is unclear on that). If yes, you should tell how you are connecting to twitter. But generally, from the tone of your questions, it seems you haven't read the documentation, on creating an app section in respective developer console, and getting app id.

Comment: Thanks bro at least after reading it few of problem has solved.But still i am mot able to find why FaceBook and twitter with my app on device ie iphone 5 not working but on simulator its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much integration you need or if your willing to require iOS 6 but in iOS 6 it is SO MUCH easier to integrate Facebook and Twitter.

This is all the code:

In the header file:

```
#import "Social/Social.h"
```

In the main file:

```
    //Twitter
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Done!");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler = myBlock;

        [controller setInitialText:@"Status Text"];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now. You must be online and signed into at least one Twitter account." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    //Facebook
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Done!");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler = myBlock;

        [controller setInitialText:@""];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Error" message:@"Either you are not logged into Facebook or your Facebook username and password are incorrect." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: can i know which third party framework you used? and what all you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Share kit framework, http://getsharekit.com

Answer (score 0):

As per integrating twitter in your application.Try this code

at self.fullimage write any url of image.

Call buildTweetSheet method to post to twitter.

import Twitter.framework

## import

@property(nonatomic,strong) TWTweetComposeViewController *_tweetSheet;

@synthesize _tweetSheet;
-(void)buildTweetSheet
{
    NSLog(@"buildTweetSheet");

```
_tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];


UIImage *eimage=UIImage *eimage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.fullimage]]];





[_tweetSheet setInitialText:@""];

[_tweetSheet addImage:eimage];

[_tweetSheet setInitialText:@""];

[self presentModalViewController:_tweetSheet animated:YES];

TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)

{
    if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Image Posted Successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Image Posted Failed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
};

[_tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
```

}